# How to automatically lock screen on closing the lid and keep programs running (not sleep) on HP Laptop

Tags: suspend, laptop, lock-screen, default-programs, lid

I wanted to keep my apps running but get the screen secured when I close the lid. I did not want to get into sleep mode as this blocked my downloads and my running music. Also, I was lazy enough that I declined to use <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> before closing the lid. All I wanted was close the lid and get it locked immediately. Please, don't use the screen saver option.

Comment: Might not be a good idea; the cooling is not sufficient with a closed lid.

Answer (score 0):

There's a fairly long way to do it so let's get to work.

It is important to understand that these events will be caught by processes owned by root. A fix is needed to allow root to run processes in the normal user's X environment. In order to make the environment variables available for root:

```
gedit ~/export_x_info
```

and paste the following contets

```
# Export the dbus session address on startup so it can be used by any other environment
sleep 5
touch $HOME/.Xdbus
chmod 600 $HOME/.Xdbus
env | grep DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS > $HOME/.Xdbus
echo 'export DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS' >> $HOME/.Xdbus
# Export XAUTHORITY value on startup so it can be used by cron
env | grep XAUTHORITY >> $HOME/.Xdbus
echo 'export XAUTHORITY' >> $HOME/.Xdbus
```

Save and close. Then make it executable:

```
chmod 700 ~/export_x_info
```

Now set it to run at startup. In Gnome 2, System> Preferences> Sessions and click Add. In Ubuntu Unity, click the gear icon in the upper right, select Startup Programs, and click Add.

```
Name: X Environment Variables
Command: /home/your_user/export_x_info
```

Now you need to edit your `/etc/acpi/lid.sh` file which catch lid open and close event

`gksudo gedit /etc/acpi/lid.sh` and paste

`/home/your_user/lid_event` just after `#!/bin/bash`. Save and close.

Now you need to create a script for close event so that you can lock your screen.

`gedit ~/lid_event` and paste the following. Change user_name with your user name

```
#!/bin/bash
grep closed /proc/acpi/button/lid/LID0/state  
 if [ $? = 0 ]
 then
 source /home/user_name/.Xdbus
 DISPLAY=:0.0 su user_name -c "gnome-screensaver-command -l"
 fi
```

also check for `/proc/acpi/button/lid/LID0/state` file using you file manager becouse LID0 may be LID.

Now restart your ACPI using

`sudo /etc/init.d/acpid restart`

Make sure that the Power Management option for laptop lid closed is set to do nothing

[source](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LaptopLidAndDockScripts)

Comment: Thank you. but I'm a new user. So, I don't know that where I paste the contets. plz, help me

Comment: Just open up a terminal from your unity menu and paste it on there. Step by step and very carefully. `gedit` is graphical so you will have the option to save the files via the GUI and close it, then come back to your terminal and do the rest.

Comment: you're welcome. please mark the question as correct if it fixed your problem so other users can benefit from it as well